# Windows security log-in using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to open a page using batch command file so that I can schedule it to open once per day. My problem is: to go to the page, I need to enter my windows access manually.

Look at this photo:
[image: photo]

Is there any way to automatically type username and password using batch file?

My current batch script:

```
@echo off  

start/min iexplore http://server/SEMs/Actions/SendNotifications.aspx  
timeout 5

taskkill /fi "WindowTitle eq SEMsNotification - Internet Explorer"
```

Comment: You're better off just solving whatever IE single sign on issue that you have. https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/258063/internet-explorer-may-prompt-you-for-a-password

Comment: Actually, I don't have any issue with that.
I'm trying to open our IIS server with windows authentication using a PC with local account.

Comment: You could try AutoIt... it's kinda hacky but it works.

Comment: I'll try that one, thank you Nick.

Comment: I'm not sure about how exactly IIS requests authentification, but maybe it's just normal HTTP auth? In that case try replacing your URL with `http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@server/SEMs/Actions/SendNotifications.aspx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, Automatically inserted my username and password using this code.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start "" /B cmd
timeout 5
set /P "= Typing password: " < NUL
%SendKeys% "MyUsername{TAB}"
%SendKeys% "MyPassword{ENTER}"
timeout 5
@end

// JScript section
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Its just simply input texts,"tab" and "enter" to the active textbox.

I used "timeout" to delay while page is loading and "SendKeys/CScript" for my input.

But I am still looking for the best answer.